# Pivot and kind of cross-join at same time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables:

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to construct a table that returns:

[image]

Where:

```
 T3.VALUE_0M column is equal to T2.VALUE if:

 T2.OLD_DATE = T1.REF_DATE and T2.ID = T1.ID 

 or:

 T3.VALUE_0M is NULL if there is no T2.OLD_DATE = T1.REF_DATE. 


 T3.VALUE_1M column is equal to T2.VALUE if:    T1.OLD_DATE =
 ADD_MONTHS(T1.REF_DATE,-1) and T2.ID = T1.ID

 or:

 T3.VALUE_1M is NULL if there is no T2.OLD_DATE =
 ADD_MONTHS(T1.REF_DATE,-1).


 T3.VALUE_2M column is equal to T2.VALUE if:

 T1.OLD_DATE = ADD_MONTHS(T1.REF_DATE,-2) and T2.ID = T1.ID


 or:
 T3.VALUE_2M is NULL if there is no T2.OLD_DATE = ADD_MONTHS(T1.REF_DATE,-2).
```

and so on.

My challenge is: if there are more than one value for the same T2.ID and T2.OLD_DATE, i want to show both of them in different rows, but crossing with the other VALUE columns.

I've tried to use cross join, but the result was not the desired:

[image]

Could be someone so kind and help me with this stuff?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand, the resulting query would be such like the below one :

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.ref_date, 
       (case when ( T1.OLD_DATE = T2.REF_DATE and T2.ID = T1.ID )
       then t1.value end) value_0m,       
       (case when ( T1.OLD_DATE = ADD_MONTHS(T2.REF_DATE,-1) and T2.ID = T1.ID  )        
       then t1.value end) value_1m,
       (case when ( T1.OLD_DATE = ADD_MONTHS(T2.REF_DATE,-2) and T2.ID = T1.ID  )
       then t1.value end) value_2m,
       (case when ( T1.OLD_DATE = ADD_MONTHS(T2.REF_DATE,-3) and T2.ID = T1.ID  )
       then t1.value 
       end) value_3m       
  FROM T1 CROSS JOIN T2;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a7671/22)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The problem is that i want to return the T1 values at the same row, like i've shown at the result example. Your query returns four unique rows.

Comment: @Douglas you're welcome. I couldn't understand the logic for the duplicate values of `value_2m` and `value_3m`.